# Problem Plotting linestyle without marker

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

So when I started my thesis, I did my first plot using the code below

```
all_timeseries_ds3.ivol.plot(label = 'Ice volume MIO_450', linestyle="-" ,  markersize=1, ax=ax1, color='y')
all_timeseries_ds7.ivol.plot(label = 'Ice volume MIO_450 threshold',  linestyle =":", ax=ax1, color='k')
```

The result is [image: picture 1]

My Professor complained and I brought it to a friend to help me and all he did was to introduce `marker` (`marker = 'o'`) and the plot became perfect with following code

```
all_timeseries_ds3.ivol.plot(label = 'Ice volume MIO_450', marker ="o", linestyle="" ,  markersize=1, ax=ax1, color='y')
all_timeseries_ds7.ivol.plot(label = 'Ice volume MIO_450 threshold' , marker ="o", linestyle="", markersize=1 ,ax=ax1, color='k')
```

The result is [image: picture 2]

Now in the above plot, the yellow line represents the total ice volume for MIO 450 with ice shelf while the black line represents the total ice volume for MIO 450 without ice shelf. Prof is of the opinion that the second line which is the black line, should be dotted or dashed and so I did this but the problem is that I am now having numerous lines like the first plot that was corrected and I used the code below

```
all_timeseries_ds3.ivol.plot(label = 'Ice volume MIO_450', marker ="o", linestyle="" ,  markersize=1, ax=ax1, color='y')
all_timeseries_ds7.ivol.plot(label = 'Ice volume MIO_450 threshold' , linestyle="", markersize=1 ,ax=ax1, color='k')
```

The result is [image: picture 4]

So in essence once I remove the `marker`, everything falls apart and I tried to use the `marker` and `linestyle` together and this appeared (picture below) with this code

```
all_timeseries_ds3.ivol.plot(label = 'Ice volume MIO_450', marker ="o", linestyle="" ,  markersize=1, ax=ax1, color='y')
all_timeseries_ds7.ivol.plot(label = 'Ice volume MIO_450 threshold' , marker ="o", linestyle=":", markersize=1 ,ax=ax1, color='k')​
```

The result is [image: picture 3]

Comment: Hm, when you use a linestyle, it joins sequential points. If there's any point in your dataframe that "goes back", then these kinds of artifacts occur. Could you do a sort of your time column and try to replot?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use df.plot.scatter to the black line values and decrease the size of the markers, something like this: df.plot.scatter(x='date', y='y', color='k', marker='.', s=0.1, ax=ax)